# How do i call wsdl webservice in Phonegap?

Tags: cordova

Here i have written my ajax call.By this same format (In url when i have written like http://xxx.yyy.z.a/WebService1/Service.asmx/add ) i can access my webservice.But i can't access the wsdl webservice.Please help me.

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 url:    "https://lifesathi.com/services/MobileAppsService.svc?wsdl",
 data: '{username:"XXXX",password:"YYYY"}',
 success: function(msg) {
 alert(msg.d);
},
error: function(msg) {
     alert("Error");
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at following links :

[Link 1](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/phonegap/jQA6dbawvvs/WL9AOa3rw-IJ)

[Link 2](http://kmithi.blogspot.in/2012/02/callling-web-services-in.html)

[Link 3](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1853-Posting-XML-SOAP-Requests-With-jQuery.htm)

[Link 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-web-services-with-jquery.aspx)

[Link 5](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-wsajax/)

Basic idea is, you might need to write a json wrapper around the soap web service so that device can send/receive requests.

For an example; Send JSON from device -> server parses JSON input -> server call SOAP with JSON input -> server parse SOAP response -> server format JSON response -> send back to phone -> phone process this JSON response